# Restricting UIScrollView scrolling to only one page at a time

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uikit, uiscrollviewdelegate

I would like to limit a `UIScrollView` to only being able to scroll one page at a time.

In other words, even when the user flicks really fast, I want the `UIScrollView` to be restricted to scrolling only one page.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

```
UIScrollView *myScrollView;
...

myScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

When set to YES, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s.

Comment: I do have paging enabled, and the scroll view does always stop on a page. However, with a fast enough swipe, it is possible to scroll two or more pages at once. This is what I am trying to stop.

Comment: Well, you did write you wanted to limit scrolling to 1 page at a time. Look at your question. You can arrange your bounds to = whatever you define to be a "Page" and see if that gets the effect you want. Else your going to have to manage that yourself.

Comment: Yeah, so far that seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Your going to have to do something like get the Swipe Gesture and if it is a swipe in whichever direction your supporting then use -(void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated

Comment: Hmm, that seems like a good idea. Then I would have full control over user interactions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this, if you haven't already settled on the scroll view, is to use a `UIPageViewController`. I'm looking at one on my app and this functionality seems to come for free.

With the UIScrollView, I'm thinking you might want to respond to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset`

I was thinking you could hold your current 'page' in a property, and then in the `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` method you could modify the target content offset to only be the next/previous page.

There's a 2012 WWDC video, Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views, that uses this approach if you wanted to see it in action.

Comment: I'm not sure about using a `UIPageViewController`, but that method you referenced definitely might be useful.

Comment: For whatever reason, the method you referenced is not called when paging is enabled (per the apple docs). Too bad, as it might have worked.

Comment: Oh, whoops didn't realize that. What you could do is have `pagingEnabled` set to `NO`, and then create that effect yourself using the above method.